# Assembly sscanf

Tags: arrays, assembly, indexing, scanf, masm

I am trying to call sscanf on a string  that would look something like "2.3 + 5.89" in assembly. I want to store the values in the array called 'values' and the operators from the string in the array called 'op'. After getting the first value i looped through the string to find the next space and find the position of the operator. My question is: how can i get the operators in the array 'op' using sscanf? What would i give the offest of the string 'exp' + the position of the operator? Or is there an easier approach for this?

```
lea edi, dword ptr values 
push dword ptr edi
push offset format
push offset exp
call sscanf
add esp, 12

mov esi,0

for_i:
inc i
mov bl,i 
inc esi
cmp exp[esi],' '
jne for_i
inc i

lea esi, dword ptr op 
push dword ptr esi
push offset format_op
push offset exp + i **--- here is my bug** 
call sscanf
add esp, 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to pass `sscanf` the address of an array element.  That means you need to do `exp + runtime_variable`, not adding two symbol addresses into an assemble-time constant.  Remember that every line of asm has to be something the machine can do in one instruction.

First of all, keep your loop counter in a register like `ebx`; don't use a static variable called `i` at all.  (EBX, ESI, EDI, EBP aren't destroyed by function calls so you can use any of them in asm the way you'd use a local variable in C.  But of course your own caller expects their values of those regs to be preserved so do that around your function.)

Then `lea esi, [exp + esi*4]` / `push esi` will compute the address and push it.